# Auto play the video doesn't work in my Android Tablet with 4.4 version

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am trying to autoplay video in my tablet(Android 4.4) but unable to autoplay. if someone please help? I am using the code below

**JS**

```
<script>
var video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
video.addEventListener('click',function(){
  video.play();
},false);
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
<video id="myVideo" width="640" height="264" autoplay ="1" loop = "1" poster="videos/plant.jpg" controls preload="auto" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;" >

<source src="videos/189.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>
</div>
```

I have tried to make autoplay ="autoplay" and autoplay..... but unsuccessfull !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the sample code for play video

```
<video controls autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

use Firefox to play smooth video

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you're using the autoplay ="autoplay" in the right place, it is the only way to do what you asked for, or try to use another browser because some browsers doesn't support the autoplay, or try to change the extension of the video to ".ogg" instead of mp4